# Raspberry Pico SDK - I2C Write to one Register Address (to set mode) then Read data from 2nd Register Address

Tags: i2c, c, pi-pico

I'm a bit confused by `i2c_write_blocking()` and how to specify the `device_address`, `register_address` and `data` to prime a device for reading and then to read data from another `2nd_register_address` in the device? I have looked at `i2c_write_blocking_internal()` in the source **i2c.c** and I get that it is looping over the bytes in `src`, to process the register address as a first byte and the transmission will complete or an abort will be triggered.

What then do we do to read data from a different `2nd_register_address` that was primed for reading by writing to the first register address? Do we do another single-byte write with the `2nd_register_address` as `src` and then do an `i2c_read_blocking()` to read the data from the device register address that was setup by the first `i2c_write_blocking()` call?

Here is the scenario. Initializing the MPU9250 magnetometer (AK8963) with full setup of all clocks and registers, you must put the chip in **FUSE mode** by writing data to the `AK8963_CNTL1` control register. The makes a read from the **FUSE ROM** possible. Then you need to read the axis sensitivity adjustments from the FUSE ROM starting at register address `AK8963_ASAX`. I just did a write to put it in FUSE mode, now do I do another write sending the `AK8963_ASAX` register address before I read the axis sensitivity adjustments?

I think this is right, but I'm sure not certain of it. With other SDK I've used, for the read/write functionality you would just load the device_address as a slave and then load the register address and then kick-off the read or write. You had ample control over the device and register address combination both writing and reading.

Here I get the SDK is shortening that process (which is good), by sending the register address as the first byte in `src` parameter with the write and for normal reads that's fine, but here where you have to send a write to put an I2C device in a particular mode -- then follow-up to read from a different address is where the confusions is.

I have no way with the read to say, just read from `AK8963_ASAX` in the call to `i2c_read_blocking()` (unless I can send the register address as the first byte in the dst parameter) -- but I haven't found any documentation that says I can. [hardware_i2c](https://raspberrypi.github.io/pico-sdk-doxygen/group__hardware__i2c.html) just says `dst` is limited to *"Pointer to buffer to receive data".* And its internal source doesn't separate an address from the `dst` argument.

Below are a couple of wrappers I added to help with `i2c_read_blocking()` and `i2c_write_blocking()` given that only the default `i2c_default` is used along with my best cut at what I need to do to put the chip in FUSE mode and then read from the `AK8963_ASAX` register:

```c
static const uint8_t mag_addr = AK8963_DEFAULT_ADDRESS;
...
/** i2c helper function for read and write with default values */
int i2c_read (uint8_t addr, const uint8_t *dst, size_t len)
{
  /* i2c_default, addr, and nostop = false (master releases bus control) */
  return i2c_read_blocking (i2c_default, addr, dst, len, false);
}

int i2c_write (uint8_t addr, const uint8_t *src, size_t len)
{
  /* i2c_default, addr, and nostop = true (master retains bus control) */
  return i2c_write_blocking (i2c_default, addr, src, len, true);
}
...

/**
 *  Initialize the AK8963 magnetometer CNTL1 by placing the magnetometer in FUSE mode
 *  to read the Axis Sensitivity Adjustment (ASA) values from FUSE_ROM, power-down
 *  the chip between mode changes and then place the magnetometer in 16-bit adc and
 *  continual measurement 2 for normal operations. Save the computed adjustments
 *  factors in asax, asay, asaz. (Page 51 & 52 of Register_Map)
 */
#ifdef MPU9250
void ak8963_initialize (void)
{
  uint8_t cntl1_mode = AK8963_CNTL1_OUT_BITS | AK8963_CNTL1_CONT_MSRMT2,
          fuse_mode = AK8963_CNTL1_OUT_BITS | AK8963_CNTL1_FUSE_ROM,
          reset = 0x00,
          regdata[2] = {0};
  
  /* set AK8963 in FUSE mode */
  regdata[0] = AK8963_CNTL1;
  regdata[1] = fuse_mode;
  i2c_write (mag_addr, regdata, sizeof regdata);
  sleep_ms (1);
  
  /* Do I do this 2nd write of the 1-byte address to prepare for the 
   * axis sensitivity read?
   */
  regdata[0] = AK8963_ASAX;
  i2c_write (mag_addr, regdata, sizeof *regdata);
  sleep_ms (1);
  
  /* read axis sensitivity adjustments */
  i2c_read (mag_addr, AK8963_ASAX, buffer, 3, false);
  sleep_ms (1);
  ...
```

Is this how you handle a prepare mode and read from different register_address scenario? Or, did I miss something basic with the `dst` parameter along the way that is now screwing me up? All thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To write bytes a, b, c to I2C device x register y**

```
output = [y, a, b, c]

i2c_write_blocking (i2c, x, &output, 4, false)
```

**To read 6 bytes from I2C device x register y**

```
output = [y]
input = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

i2c_write_blocking (i2c, x, &output, 1, true)
i2c_read_blocking (i2c, x, &input, 6, false)
```

Comment: Bingo! That's what I was thinking but I damn sure wasn't firm on it. Now I can finish moving my mpu library from TI to Pi.. Thank you.

Comment: While I'm thinking about it, why is `nostop` `false` on the first write of `[y, a, b, c]`? I thought the Pico would always want to remain master on writes?

Comment: The documentation for the device should say if a STOP is required or not.  Normally a STOP would not be required between specifying a register address and the corresponding read.  A lot of devices are quite forgiving in this regard and do not punish a wrong STOP.

Comment: Thank you again. That makes sense. It's been a while since I've been through all the NACKs and STOPs for the mpu and magnetometer chips. I suspect they are forgiving given the way the board was brought up in the pico-examples/i2c-mpu example. One of theses days I'll make friends will microcontrollers proving the "old dogs and new tricks" phrase wrong `:)`

Comment: This is helpful; it solved my immediate problem, but now I have another Q: My device has 8 registers - 0x00 - 0x03, 0x06, 0x07, 0xFE, 0xFF, and I need to read (for example) 0x01 - 0x03 repetitively. Can that be done by declaring `output` with 3 elements, and looping through for 0x01 through 0x03?